# Want to merge more than one .txt file contents to one text file using batch script?

Tags: eclipse

I am trying to build my C++ eclipse project from command line.
Below is the command I have given  ,

```
C:\Piranha_Development_Tools\Eclipse_Kepler_64bit\eclipsec.exe -nosplash -application org.eclipse.cdt.managedbuilder.core.headlessbuild -data 
C:\Test_Trunk\TrunkTestWS - build k64f
```

Then I am getting below error,

[image]

Version: Kepler Release
Build id: 20130614-0229

Please let me know If I have to try something or if any link I can refer.

Comment: The topic title does not match the topic content at all...

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the time to read [The Tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and refer to the material from the [Help Center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) what and how you can ask here.